# How to change odoo 12 view display properly?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

Hi how to change odoo 12 view.xml to add more column, or add something in the module? i trying to create odoo 12 module from scratch using command like this

> & "c:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\python.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo-bin" scaffold ms_produk
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons"

then my base project generated, and then i trying to add model named "produk.py" in models folder which is look like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class ProdukProduk(models.Model):
    _name = 'ms_produk.ms_produk'

    kd_produk = fields.Char(String='Kode Produk', required=True)
    nm_produk = fields.Char(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
```

then in the same folder i edit files named **init**.py and add an import, which is looked like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import models
from . import produk
```

then i add a view for my module, i go to views folder and add a file named master_produk_view.xml then i add some code that looked like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="masterproduk_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Master Produk</field>
            <field name="res_model">ms_produk.ms_produk</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create Product
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="masterproduk_menu" name="MasterProduk"/>
        <menuitem id="Masterproduk_new_product_menu" 
                parent="masterproduk_menu" 
                name="New Produk"
                action="masterproduk_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

booms, and my module is complete with CRUD action, but when i looked at the view, it's not showing all of my database column, only showing ID column, which is i think it should showing kd_produk and nm_produk column, how do i change this?

i trying to modified the view xml code to be looked like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="masterproduk_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Master Produk</field>
            <field name="res_model">ms_produk.ms_produk</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="kd_produk"/>
                    <field name="nm_produk"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create Product
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="masterproduk_menu" name="MasterProduk"/>
        <menuitem id="Masterproduk_new_product_menu" 
                parent="masterproduk_menu" 
                name="New Produk"
                action="masterproduk_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

and nothing happened, it still showing ID column only, which is drive me nuts, i already restart my odoo server, upgrade the module in apps option, what did i missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding form view in your model

```
  <record id="id" model="ir.ui.view">
       <field name="name">name</field>
       <field name="model">ms_produk.ms_produk</field>
       <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <form string="form string">
             define fields you want in your view
            </form>
        </field>
   </record>
```

you can also add tree view

```
<record id="id" model="ir.ui.view">
       <field name="name">name</field>
       <field name="model">ms_produk.ms_produk</field>
       <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <tree string="Tree string">
              fields in tree view
           </tree>
       </field>
   </record>
```

and load it into action.
you can refer this [link](http://odootechnical.com/how-to-create-a-form-view-in-odoo-8/).

Comment: you're right! i need add ir.ui.view model! that's what i missed.. thanks man

Comment: sorry i need to ask little bit, after i add ir.ui.view why i can't click the row and go to the detail?

Comment: It is defined in ir.actions.act_window in that you need load tree and form accordingly

Comment: okay thank you mr @thayif kabir it work now, i think it's cache stuff haha